# How to write range with variable in vba

Tags: excel, vba7

I am unable to write vba code where mentioned range has variable which is changing with every iteration.

Here is a code

```
Letter = "H"

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng = Range("J5:J" & LastRow)

For Each cell In Rng

If cell.Text <> "" Then

'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plg").Range("G6: N6").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Rng)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plg").Range("G6: Letter" & 6).Value =Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Rng) ' Giving error

End If 

Letter = Chr(Asc(Letter) + 1)

Next cell
```

I want my code to perform like a quoted statement however it is giving an error.

Comment: Don't use `Range` and a letter. Use `Cells` and a number.

Comment: so [edit] to quote the error... and preferably to indent/format your code properly too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't doing the concatenation properly - `Letter` should not be inside the quotes.

This is how the concatenation should be done.

```vb
    Letter = "H"

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

    Set Rng = Range("J5:J" & LastRow)

    For Each cell In Rng

        If cell.Text <> "" Then

            'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plg").Range("G6: N6").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Rng)

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plg").Range("G6:" & Letter & "6").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Rng)    ' Giving error

        End If

        Letter = Chr(Asc(Letter) + 1)

    Next cell
```

You could also do it without concatenation by setting up the destination range at the start and then resizing it on each iteration of the loop.

```vb
Dim rngDst As Range
Dim rngSrc As Range

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rngSrc = Range("J5:J" & LastRow)
    Set rngDst = Sheets("Plg").Range("G6:H6")

    For Each cell In Rngsrt

        If cell.Text <> "" Then

            'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plg").Range("G6: N6").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Rng)

            rngDst.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rngSrc)    ' Giving error

        End If

        Set rngDst = rngDst.Resize(, rngDst.Columns.Count + 1)

    Next cell
```

You could also use Cells instead of Range as BigBen suggested.

```vb
    lngColNo = 8

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

    Set Rng = Range("J5:J" & LastRow)

    For Each cell In Rng

        If cell.Text <> "" Then

            'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plg").Range("G6: N6").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Rng)

            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plg")
                .Range("G6", .Cells(6, lngColNo)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Rng)    ' Giving error
            End With
        End If

        lngColNo = lngColNo + 1

    Next cell
```

Both of these options are preferable to using concatenation, mainly because updating the column letter isn't going to work beyond column Z using the current code.