# Using variables to select a Range

Tags: excel, vba

```
Set rng = Sheets("combine").Range("b" & (startb)":j" & (startj)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

i need help to pass variables into range when selecting cells.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write range with variable in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67674856/how-to-write-range-with-variable-in-vba)

Comment: Why don't you share the preceding code. There is not enough context. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70910697/edit) your post at any time.

Comment: `... .Range("b" & startb & ":j" & startj). ...`

Answer (score 0):

By passing variables, you can try another indexing, like

```
sh = Sheets("combine")
sh.Range(sh.Cells(row_x,col_x),sh.Cells(row_xx,col_yy))
```